# Django - 'extra_fields' in CustomModelForm is giving 'Unable to lookuup' error in models inline interface when trying to load that form

Tags: python, django

I've one app named `Question` where i defined two models `Question` and `Alternative` in models.py as follows :

```
class Question(models.Model):

    question = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=1)


class Alternative(models.Model):

    alternative = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i've made a Custom form `AlternativeForm` where i've created a extra field which i want to appear in my `Alternative forms` as well as `Question` admin view where Alternative fields will appear in the inline view **But the extra field value will not be saved in DB**(cause i want to do some manual operations with the value of that fields). my `forms.py` is as follows:

```
class AlternativeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    extra_field = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        extra_field = self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field', None)
        # will do something with extra_field here...
        return super(AlternativeForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        model = Alternative
        fields = '__all__'
```

and in my `admin.py` i've made an inline relationship between them as follows:

```
class AlternativeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    form = AlternativeForm
    model = Alternative

@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AlternativeInline,]

@admin.register(Alternative)
class AlternativeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Alternative
    form  = AlternativeForm
```

I'm getting `AttributeError: Unable to lookup 'extra_field' on Alternative or AlternativeInline` in this case. I want **to show those extra field** in the **Inline view** of `Question`apps admin view. Is there any way to do it or what is wrong in my current approach.
Thanks.

Comment: That issue is a bug, fixed in [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30520#ticket).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution when speculating this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701930/in-django-inline-model-admin-how-to-prefill-extra-fields-with-values). One should define the `label` field in the custom field like the following to avoid such error `AttributeError: Unable to lookup 'extra_field' on Alternative or AlternativeInline`.

```
class AlternativeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    extra_field = forms.BooleanField(label='is_answer', required=False)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # extra_field = self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field', None)
        # ...do something with extra_field here...
        return super(AlternativeForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

Comment: I have been spending a lot of time with this scenario ahahaha, thank you a lot sir! on my case I needed a `hiddenfield` and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

To have the extra fields in the admin:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = YourModelForm

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('other fields here', 'extra_field',),
        }),
    )
```

Comment: Actually the problem here is `extra_fields` are appearing in the corresponding model's (Alternative) admin view but not appearing in `Question` model admin view which has inline relationship with `Alternative` model. @ManzurulHoqueRumi