# Extra field of ModelForm without label, does not render in InlineModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, modelform

To add an extra field in the admin `add` page, the following code will work:

models.py:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    pass


class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

forms.py:

```py
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = '__all__'
```

admin.py:

```py
@admin.register(models.Child)
class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = forms.ChildForm
```

---

**How** can I add the same extra field when `Child` is an inline to `Parent` in the `Parent` `add` page?

---

The following admin.py:

```py
class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = models.Child
    form = forms.ChildForm


@admin.register(models.Parent)
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ChildInline,)
```

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "django/db/models/options.py", line 617, in get_field
    return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'extra_field'

...

django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Child has no field named 'extra_field'

...

AttributeError: Unable to lookup 'extra_field' on Child or ChildInline
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change the `ParentForm`?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy This is a good idea. I need arbitrary instances of a form with an `extra_field` inside the `ParentForm`, how could that go? Like a formset inside the `ParentForm(ModelForm)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511865/django-extra-fields-in-custommodelform-is-giving-unable-to-lookuup-error-i), adding a label, will make the inlines work as expected:

```
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    extra_field = forms.CharField(label='Extra Field')

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = '__all__'
```

Relevant ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30520#ticket